# Add column and update it within a transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to add and update a column. This code is within a transaction.

```
ALTER TABLE [Foo] ADD SomeId INT NULL
UPDATE [Foo] SET SomeId = 1
ALTER TABLE [Foo] ALTER COLUMN SomeId INT NOT NULL
```

I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Invalid column name 'SomeId'.

I tried adding a `GO` statement after the first`ALTER TABLE`, but apparently that's invalid inside a transaction. How can I make this work inside a transaction?

Comment: I did some testing in SQL 2012 and had inconsistent results.  I think the problem is that all three commands are executed in the same batch.  SQL can't compile line 2 or 3 because the column doesn't exist yet.  If I added `GO` after the  `ALTER TABLE` statement, the code runs as two batches and I don't have any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Begin Try

Begin Tran

Alter Table [Foo] Add SomeId INT NOT NULL Constraint TempConstraint Default  (1)
Alter Table [Foo] Drop TempConstraint

End Tran
```

Essentially what this is doing is adding the new column with a default value constraint of 1. All current rows will get a value of 1. Then the default value constraint is being removed, so there will be no default value.

Since you can't mix DDL and DML statements in a single transaction, like what you wanted to do originally, this is your only alternative.

Comment: So why is that necessary if the column is NULLable?

Comment: It's necessary because you want each existing row to contain a value of 1. If you didn't provide a default value, each row would have a value of NULL.